# counter timer is not stop even after finish the activity

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a quiz app which has a timer for the whole game-activity where in you should answer as 20 questions and every qustion have 10 sec ..

after the assigned 20 is over, it will take you to the results activity which shows your score. even after calling score activity toast from main activty will show and score activity will open agian and again.

```
int score = 0;
int unanswer = 0;
int questionasked = 1;
int maxquestion = 20;
TextView first, operator, second, timeview;
Button A, B, C, D;
int ans = 0;
String t;
DecimalFormat df;
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    timeview = findViewById(R.id.time);
    A = findViewById(R.id.A);
    A.setOnClickListener(this);
    B = findViewById(R.id.B);
    B.setOnClickListener(this);
    C = findViewById(R.id.C);
    C.setOnClickListener(this);
    D = findViewById(R.id.D);
    D.setOnClickListener(this);
    first = findViewById(R.id.first);
    second = findViewById(R.id.second);
    operator = findViewById(R.id.operator);
    df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
    starTimer();
    fillValue();

}
```

> main activity code

```
private void fillValue() {
    if (questionasked > maxquestion)
        showscore();
    questionasked++;
    int a = (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);
    int op = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    int buttonoption = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    char operatorcharter = '+';
    switch (op) {
        case 1:
            ans = a + b;
            operatorcharter = '+';
            break;
        case 2:
            ans = a - b;
            operatorcharter = '-';
            break;
        case 3:
            ans = a * b;
            operatorcharter = 'X';
            break;
        case 4:
            ans = (a) / b;
            operatorcharter = '/';
            break;
        //default:
        //Toast.makeText(this,op+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    //Toast.makeText(this,a+" "+operatorcharter+" "+b+" "+ans+" "+buttonoption,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    operator.setText(operatorcharter + "");
    first.setText(a + "");
    second.setText(b + "");
    t = df.format(ans);
    int temp = 0;
    switch (buttonoption) {
        case 1:
            A.setText(t);
            break;
        case 2:
            B.setText(t);
            break;
        case 3:
            C.setText(t);
            break;
        case 4:
            D.setText(t);
            break;
        //default:
        // Toast.makeText(this,buttonoption+" butt",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (i == buttonoption)
            continue;
        temp = (int) (Math.random() * ans + 1);
        if (temp == ans) ;
        temp += 5;
        String temp1 = df.format(temp);
        if (i == 1)
            A.setText(temp1 + "");
        else if (i == 2)
            B.setText(temp1 + "");
        else if (i == 3)
            C.setText(temp1 + "");
        else if (i == 4)
            D.setText(temp1 + "");
    }
    mCountDownTimer.start();
}

private void showscore() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, final_activity.class);
    i.putExtra(Contact.maxquestion, maxquestion);
    i.putExtra(Contact.score, score);
    i.putExtra(Contact.unanswer, unanswer);
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    Toast.makeText(this, "new activity open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    startActivity(i);
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    String clickbuttonvalue = (String) b.getText();
    if (clickbuttonvalue.equals(t))
        score++;
    //Toast.makeText(this,score+"  "+clickbuttonvalue   ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    fillValue();
}


public void starTimer() {
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeview.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "new" + millisUntilFinished / 1000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            unanswer++;
            fillValue();
        }

    }.start();
}
```

}

this is my code even after opening new activity and open new activity check method showscore() 
plz, help!

Comment: cancel it onStop or onDestory based on Logic, and CountDown onTick is never accurate, switch it to handler, more efficicent

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `onDestroy` method which will be triggered when the activity is finished(don't forget to add `finish()` after the `startActivty()`).

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
}
```